# What is difference between TinkerPop and TitanDB?

Tags: bigdata, graph-databases, titan

As a beginner, Want to know the difference between TinkerPop and Titan

Answer (score 2):

TitanDB is a graph database engine with a different backend storage ( like Cassandra etc ) and an optional query index ( like elasticsearch etc.. ) . In other words it creates property graph data models and stores it in one of the many supported backend stores and for optional faster querying relies on products like elasticsearch etc for indexing...

Tinkerpop is a framework that sits on top of titanDB. It also supports other graph databases like Neo4j for example. One of the many features implemented in tinkerpop is the gremlin graph query language (analogous to SQL for relational db) that interacts with graph databases like Titan to help the user create and query graph data.